# Delete character from string in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to remove a character from a string. For example:

```
?- remove_char('abcde', 'c', X).
X = 'abde'

?- remove_char('abcdefgh', 'f', X).
X = 'abcdegh'
```

I'm looking for a concise way of accomplishing this, but I have no success. I'm new to Prolog and I'm having a very hard time dealing with strings if I don't want to convert them to lists. Is there a built in function for this, or at least a parsimonious way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sub_atom/5 could help, anyway here is an alternative.

```
remove_char(S,C,X) :- atom_concat(L,R,S), atom_concat(C,W,R), atom_concat(L,W,X).
```

Since [atom_concat](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atom_concat/3) is well implemented, remove_char it's more general than its name suggests:

```
2 ?- remove_char(abcabcd,bc,X).
X = aabcd ;
X = abcad ;
false.
```

A good exercise would be to try to implement the same logic (for 'fragments' extraction) with sub_atom/5.

Comment: Your code looks like sorcery to me, but I'm glad it works. I don't really understant why it does what it does, even though I know atom_concat/3 predicate. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

You're not dealing with string in your code: `'abcde'` is an atom. `"abcde"` is a prolog string (aka list of characters). However, this seems pretty concise to me, if you want to play with atoms:

```
remove_chars( X , C , Y ) :-
  atom_chars( X , Xs ) ,
  strip( Xs , C , Ys ) ,
  atom_chars( Y , Ys )
  .

strip( []     , _ , []     ) .
strip( [Y|Cs] , C , [Y|Ys] ) :- Y \= C , strip(Cs,C,Ys) .
strip( [Y|Cs] , C ,    Ys  ) :- Y  = C , strip(Cs,C,Ys) .
```

Or, using the built-in `select/3`, even more concise:

```
remove_chars( X , C , Y ) :-
  atom_chars( X , Xs ) ,
  select( C, Xs , Ys ) ,
  atom_chars( Y , Ys )
  .
```

Comment: strip/3 seems useless, why not select/3 ?

Comment: If you're trying to learn prolog, rolling your own helps understanding. Added that as an alternative.

Comment: I didn't know it was called "atom". Thanks for pointing that out!